# How much do you earn for a delivery?

Tags: railroad-tycoon

What is the formula for the amount of money you receive for a delivery in the original Railroad Tycoon?

The manual is clearly wrong when it says bulk goods produce the same payment no matter how long they took or how far they travelled, because an actual game shows varying amounts.

I saw a formula in a book once, but by the time I returned to the bookstore the book had unfortunately been sold!

Comment: I'm assuming you used the `railroad-tycoon-2` tag because a tag for the first one didn't exist. I created that tag for you and retagged the question.

Comment: Correct assumption, thanks. Not many players of the original game now! I looked everywhere to see whether a newbie could propose a new tag, without success.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But high-rep users are often quick to correct this, as long as the intended game is clear and the question shows your best effort.

Answer (score 2):

> Calculation of Revenues:
>
> There is a series of four calculations that
>   are run on each commodity on each delivery.   They must be done in the
>   order listed in this chart.  The total revenue for the run is
>   determined by adding the results of the calculations below for each
>   commodity.  To that will be addad any station-specific modifiers such
>   as restraunt/hotel income for passenger deliveries.
>
> Variables:
>   DIST = # squares between stations (* .5 if E. USA or
>   England)
>   DISTB and DISTC = Interim variables in formulas   SPEED =
>   Mph/2.5 (i.e. 20mph = speed of 8)   CLASS = 0 for Ma, 1 for Passenger,
>   2 for Fast Freight, 3 for Slow Freight    and 4 for Bulk Freight)
>   DIFF = Difficulty level (0 for investor ... 3 for Tycoon)
>   REVENUEA = Interim variable in formula
>   FIRST YEAR = The first year of the
>   scenario
>   REVENUE = Revenue for cargo
>
> Calculation #1:  Effect of Distance
>   DISTB = DIST*(5 - CLASS) + (40*(CLASS+1))
>
> Calculation #2:  Effect of Speed
>   DISTC = (DISTB/8)*(SPEED +  (2*CLASS^2) / (((YEAR-1790)/10) + (2*CLASS^2))
>
> Calculation #3:  Effect of Year
>   REVENUEA = TONS*2*DISTC / (YEAR - (1170 + (FIRST YEAR/3)))
>
> Calculation #4:  Effect of Difficulty Level
>   REVENUE = REVENUEA * (7 - DIFF) / 6

I've found these formulas [here](http://home.comcast.net/~dmitton/rrt-faq.txt) and [here](http://www.florian-sartorius.de/railroad.htm),both quoting ["The Official Guide to Sid Meier's Railroad Tycoon](https://books.google.de/books/about/The_Official_Guide_to_Sid_Meier_s_Railro.html?id=0-0_OgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)" as their source.

Comment: That should keep me quiet for a while. Great! However, the manual says that in the Western USA scenario north-south trips earn much less than east-west trips. Am I right in guessing that "DIST" would be calculated accordingly? So a ten-square trip due south would have DIST=5 and the same due west would have DIST=20?

Comment: The only negative factor given is -50%,so I'd assume that "much less" equals "you get half the DIST".That would mean that a ten-square trip would have DIST=5 for the south and DIST=10 for the west.I'm not entirely sure,because the only zones that are written to have this malus are eastern USA and England,so I guess you have to check this for yourself by calculating your estimated and actual result.

Comment: The actual wording says that prices are doubled for east-west trips and halved for north-south trips. Where is the "-50%" you say is given?